# Sequelize bulkCreate within a transaction

Tags: transactions, sequelize.js

I'm trying to execute a truncate and bulk create within a transaction using sequelize. However, the bulkcreate is never executed. My code for this is as follows:

```
            sequelize.transaction(function(t) {
                return Item.destroy({ truncate: true, transaction: t }).then(() => {
                    return Item.bulkCreate(itemsArray, {transaction: t})
                })
            }).catch(function (err) {
                logger.error('ERROR:' + err);
            });
```

The logs for this are as follows:

```
5:21:23 PM - info: Successfully connected to DB:XXX
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (`barcode` 
VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `base` INTEGER, `original` INTEGER, `sale` INTEGER, 
`extraSale` INTEGER, `date` DATETIME, PRIMARY KEY (`barcode`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `items`
Executing (83dc186e-dec7-4814-94fd-f05cebc0e48b): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (83dc186e-dec7-4814-94fd-f05cebc0e48b): TRUNCATE `items`
5:21:02 PM - info: here
Executing (83dc186e-dec7-4814-94fd-f05cebc0e48b): COMMIT;
```

If I change the function so that I use create it works as expected.

Anyone any ideas why bulkCreate isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the above is correct. The issue was that due to the async nature of the code I had a cleanup function that would empty out the array ready for the next iteration. This function was firing before the bulkcreate and hence the create didn't fire as the items array was empty.

Updated solution is below.

```
            sequelize.transaction(function(t) {
                return Item.destroy({ truncate: true, transaction: t }).then(() => {
                    return Item.bulkCreate(itemsArray, { transaction: t }).then(() => {
                        //Ensure we are cleaned-up ready for the next iteration
                        //Have to clean up here due to async callback
                        itemsArray = [];
                    }, err => {
                        logger.error('ERROR:' + err);
                    })
                }, err => {
                    logger.error('ERROR:' + err);
                })
            }).catch(function (err) {
                logger.error('ERROR:' + err);
            });
```